# gdal_calc --hideNoData not working in python script

Tags: gdal, nodata, gdal-calc

I am trying to convert the following GDAL code which works perfectly in the command shell into a python script

```
gdal_calc --calc "(A == 0) * B + (A != 0) * A" --format GTiff --type Float32 -A C:\Users\Public\try\singlebeam.tif --A_band 1 -B C:\Users\Public\try\gdaltry.tif --B_band 1 --outfile C:/Users/public/OUTPUT90.tif --hideNoData
```

I have written this ...

```
import os

gdal_path = r'"C:/Program Files/QGIS 3.16/apps/Python37/Scripts"'
gdal_calc_path = os.path.join(gdal_path, 'gdal_calc.py')

# Arguements.
input_file_path = 'C:/Users/Public/try/singlebeam.tif'
input_file_path2 = 'C:/Users/Public/try/gdaltry.tif'
output_file_path = 'C:/Users/Public/try/pytry3.tif'
calc_expr = '"(A == 0) * B + (A != 0) * A"'
typeof = '"Float32"'

# Generate string of process.
gdal_calc_str = 'python {0} -A {1} -B {2} --outfile={3} --calc={4} --type={5} --hideNoData'
gdal_calc_process = gdal_calc_str.format(gdal_calc_path, input_file_path, input_file_path2,
    output_file_path, calc_expr, typeof)

# Call process.
os.system(gdal_calc_process)
```

However, I am getting the error `gdal_calc.py: error: no such option: --hideNoData`

I need the `--hideNoData` function as otherwise my NoDataValue are not participating in the calculation.

Comment: What does `where gdal_calc` return on the command line?  I suspect you have multiple versions of gdal installed and you're pointed at a different one from the gdal_calc that's in the system path

Comment: @mikewatt on the command line it runs perfectly with the count ```1.....1.....1......2.....2, etc``` and the desired output saved as expected. However, it is just when I transfer it to a python script that I am getting the error regarding ```--hideNoData```. If I remove the ```--hideNoData``` the code works

Comment: Understood.  Can you answer the question in my first comment?